# Access to the VCS Tree button in custom plugin

Tags: teamcity

I'm building a custom plugin in-house, and I'm trying to figure out how to get the VCS tree button to show on a text field.  I've looked at the NuGet source as some of the inputs on those runners have it, but there's nothing in there that would show how the VCS tree button is placed.  No tag or JS to add the button.

Do we have access to the VCS tree button or is this private?
If we do, what should I look at?

Here's the link to one of the .jsp's in the NuGet source:

http://git.jetbrains.org/?p=teamcity/dotNetPackagesSupport.git;a=blob;f=nuget-server/resources/publish/editPublish.jsp;h=480591aecb80a819932d81e328ef97fd8990fe15;hb=HEAD

**EDIT:**
So I was able to find the jsp file that is used by the distro of TeamCity.  It's used as such:

```
<bs:vcsTree fieldId="fieldToPopulate"></bs:vcsTree>
```

But I can't figure out what .jar I need to add.  What .jar is this tag a part of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag is not a part of any jar. You should add this taglib reference

```
<%@ taglib prefix="bs" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

to your page.

Beware though, that it is not a part of open api, so the location might change in future TeamCity versions